# Jest unit test - global variable modified in a function which is being tested is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm new to JEST and trying to write unit test cases for a tsx file. I'm trying to test a function which takes in an argument and sets the value of a global variable (x) equal to the argument passed. When I run the test, I get the value as undefined. Here is the code :

.TSX FILE

```
import { Component, Event, EventEmitter, Method, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

import { CountryLanguageSelectorModel } from './country-language-selector.model';

@Component({
  tag: 'dxp-country-language-selector',
  styleUrls: ['dxp-country-language-selector.css'],
  shadow: false
})
export class CountryLanguageSelector {
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) contentData: CountryLanguageSelectorModel;
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) contentPath = '../assets/mock.json';
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) modalView: boolean;
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) selectedCountry: string;
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) selectedLanguage: string;
  @Event() countrySelected: EventEmitter;
  @Event() languageSelected: EventEmitter;

  componentWillLoad () {
    this.getData(this.contentPath)
      .then(data => {
        this.contentData = data;
        this.selectedCountry = this.contentData.countryList[0];
        this.selectedLanguage = this.contentData.languageList[0];
      });
  }

  @Method()
  getData (contentPath: string): Promise<CountryLanguageSelectorModel> {
    if (contentPath) {
      return fetch(contentPath)
        .then((response: any) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            return Promise.resolve(null);
          }
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(this.contentData);
    }
  }

  countrySelectedHandler (selectedCountry) {
    this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry.target.value;
    this.countrySelected.emit(selectedCountry.target.value);
  }

  languageSelectedHandler (selectedLanguage) {
    this.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage.target.value;
    this.languageSelected.emit(selectedLanguage.target.value);
  }

  render () {
    if (this.contentData) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div id="country-selector" class="country-selector primary-light" onClick={() => { this.modalView = true }}>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <p class="globe-wrapper"></p>
              <a href="#." class="clang-selector" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span
                class="country">{this.selectedCountry}
                <span class="down-arrow"></span>
            </span><span class="lang small">{this.selectedLanguage}</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          { this.modalView ?
            <div class="modal main-section col-12 visible" id="modal">
              <div class="modal-dialog col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-10 primary-light">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="btn-close" id="closeBtn"
                      onClick={() => this.modalView = false}><span
                  class="icon icon-close"></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p><a href="" aria-label="go to">
                    {/*<span class="mastercard-logo"></span>*/}
                    <img src={this.contentData.imageUrl}></img>
                  </a></p>
                  <h5>{this.contentData.title}</h5>
                  <p>{this.contentData.subtitle}</p>
                  <div id="country">
                    <div>Country</div>
                    <select title="Select your country" aria-label="Select your country"
                            onInput={event => this.countrySelectedHandler(event)}>
                      {this.contentData.countryList.map(country =>
                        <option>{country}</option>
                      )}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <p></p>
                  <div id="lang">
                    <div>Language</div>
                    <select title="Select your language" aria-label="Select your language"
                            onInput={event => this.languageSelectedHandler(event)}>
                      {this.contentData.languageList.map(language =>
                        <option>{language}</option>
                      )}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-cta btn-brick" id="go-back"
                          onClick={() => this.modalView = false}>{this.contentData.buttonText}</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> : '' }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

================Unit Test======================

```
     import { TestWindow } from '@stencil/core/testing'

import { CountryLanguageSelector } from './dxp-country-language-selector'

let obj = new CountryLanguageSelector();
window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(contentPath => {
  if (contentPath === '../assets/mock.json') {
    return Promise.resolve({
      json: () => {
        return {
          'title': 'Select Country',
          'subtitle': 'Lorem Ipsum',
          'logoPath': '../images/icons/logo.svg',
          'countryList': ['India', 'USA', 'Australia'],
          'languageList': ['English', 'Hindi', 'French'],
          'buttonText': 'Go Back To Site'
        };
      }
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('error');
  }
});

describe('CountryLanguageSelector', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    obj = new CountryLanguageSelector();
  });
```

======This is failing===========

```
  // it('should set the passed argument as selected country', () => {
  //   let country = { target : { value: '' } } ;
  //   country.target.value = 'India';
  //   obj.languageSelectedHandler(country);
  //   expect(obj.selectedLanguage).toEqual('India');
  // });
});
```

====================================

Comment: There is no global variable in the code you've posted. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There is no class you're testing. The test fails because some parts of it don't work as you expect.

Comment: @estus I haven't posted the whole file here. The global variable in the function is `selectedCountry` which is easily understood.

Comment: The whole file is not necessary, but the question should contain all relevant code.

Comment: The question is containing all the necesary code. Unit tests are meant to test functions in isolation. Whole code or class is not required.

Comment: I agree that they need to be tested in isolation. Sadly, it's impossible to say why the value undefined this way. This was your question, wasn't it? Because the code that is responsible for this behaviour is not shown. There is no code that sets `selectedLanguage`.

Comment: Hey @estus, I have added full code. Please have a look now

Comment: I see. I don't use Stencil myself but here it seems to not affect anything. What exactly is the message the test fail with? From the code above, I would expect that if `obj` is an instance of `CountryLanguageSelector` , `obj.languageSelectedHandler(country)` will set `obj.selectedLanguage`, there are no ambiguities.

Comment: I got that working. Thanks for your support. I am facing some other issues with the testing of render function, will ask a separate question on that. The problem with this one was some mocking of class

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.